# Group by totals as other column values using access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table A

```
 EK_ID  ECID    WCD    WCP
1004    1001    2        0
1004    1001    2        5
1004    1001    3        2
1005    1025    2        5
1005    1025    4        3
1006    1025    6        2
1006    1025    5        8
```

I'm trying to write Sum of WC_D, WC_P columns(Group by EK_ID) result as other  column values(Repeats the totals based on EK_ID). The result table should looks like . I have a situation where I need to divide WCD values by its totals.

```
EK_ID   ECID  WCD  WCP  Total_WCD  Total_WCP
1004    1001    2   0          7      7
1004    1001    2   5          7      7
1004    1001    3   2          7      7
1005    1025    2   5          6      8
1005    1025    4   3          6      8
1006    1025    6   2          11     10
1006    1025    5   8          11     10
```

Comment: Does MS Access support correlated sub-queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this query:

```
SELECT EK_ID, Sum(WCD) AS Total_WCD, Sum(WCP) AS Total_WCP FROM table GROUP BY EK_ID
```

Then the table in the format you requested is:

```
SELECT table.EK_ID, table.ECID, table.WCD, table.WCP, query.Total_WCD, query.Total_WCP
FROM table INNER JOIN query ON table.EK_ID=query.EK_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select YT.*,T.*
from #YourTable YT
join (
    select EK_ID, SUM(WCD) as Total_WCD, SUM(WCP) as Total_WCP
    from #YourTable YT
    group by EK_ID
) T on T.EK_ID = YT.EK_ID
```

full example

```
    create table #YourTable(EK_ID int, ECID int, WCD int,  WCP int)
insert into #YourTable
select 1004, 1001, 2, 0
union select 1004, 1001, 2, 5
union select 1004, 1001, 3, 2
union select 1005, 1025, 2, 5
union select 1005, 1025, 4, 3
union select 1006, 1025, 6, 2
union select 1006, 1025, 5, 8



select YT.*,T.*
from #YourTable YT
join (
    select EK_ID, SUM(WCD) as Total_WCD, SUM(WCP) as Total_WCP
    from #YourTable YT
    group by EK_ID
) T on T.EK_ID = YT.EK_ID
```

Comment: Right idea, but your syntax is not necessarily 100% compatible with MS Access.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I registered only 2 day ago on stackoverflow :)  I missed tag MS Access